# SQL Server 2012 DataTools + Visual Studio 2012 = An incompatible DacFx version is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm going crazy, trying to use SSDT in Visual Studio 2012. I created a database but I can't add tables etc. because of this error.

I installed:

- Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate
- SQL Server 2012 Express x64 with Advanced Services, plus WinUpdates
- Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools - Business Intelligence for Visual Studio 2012 x86 (couldn't find a specific x64 version)
- SQL Server 2012 Data-Tier Application Framework (August 2013 both x86-x64 versions)

Basically I followed this MSDN piece of advice, http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/04ee07bf-31d9-4a60-90ad-bf48c16eb4d1/ssdt-vs2012-error-dac-framework-compatibility?forum=ssdt
but without results

Is there something I have to do, or follow a particular order?

Really this stuff is driving me crazy

Thx evbdy

Comment: :( anybody solutions?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to download the latest version of SSDT from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh297027. Or you should be able to get it inside Visual Studio by choosing "SQL-> Check for Updates" from the top menu bar. This will install the latest SSDT and DacFx bits, and fix this error.

Unfortunately SSDT and SSDT-BI have confusingly similar names but are separate downloads with different functionality. That's why your installation of the SSDT-BI tool didn't fix this error.